# React - Check if a value already exists in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, arraylist

I'm working on a simple React shopping list where you can add/remove items from a list ([pen here](https://codepen.io/ash-thomas/pen/pBzqJN)). It's working great so far except if you add a duplicate entry to the list and try and delete it, it gets confused (it's using the value as the key, so presumably that's why). To get around this I'd like to check if the value already exists in the list array when you add an item, and prevent it from being added. I've tried adding another check in the handleAddNew function by changing this: `if (this.state.newItem.length > 0){` to this: `if (this.state.newItem.length > 0 && this.state.items.includes(this.state.newItem) == false){` (line 18), but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Please post your code here, not behind an external link.

Comment: try by using some() ,it will work
array.some(function(o){return o["key1"] === "value2";})
will be true if pair is found, otherwise false.

Comment: `if (this.state.newItem.length  && !this.state.items.includes(this.state.newItem))`  you can use this

Comment: Thanks @NarendraChouhan, this also worked as well as Matt Way's answer below. I prefer this answer as it doesn't remove the text input entry when you click 'add item'.

Comment: my pleasure @Godge can you mark the answer as correct, if you feel my answer works for you i have posted the code below

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised after a little more testing that it doesn't seem to work, and prevents the value from being added if the original duplicate has been removed. @Matt Way's answer seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the entry form doesn't have access to the list to do any comparison. You can achieve your original thought by altering the `addItem` function to:

```
addItem(item) {
  // only add if the item doesn't exist in the list
  if(this.state.items.indexOf(item) < 0){
    this.setState((state) => ({
      items: state.items.concat([item])
    }))
  }
}
```

Note that I use `indexOf` here, but `includes` is also fine. You can do the comparison however you like.

Comment: Thanks @MattWay, this did the trick! I must admit, I prefer @NarendraChouhan's answer, as it doesn't fire the `this.setState({ newItem: '' })` code, removing the text from the input, but otherwise it works just as well.

Comment: Edit: Ignore my previous comment, after I tested it a little more, I realized @NarendraChouhan's prevents the item from being added if the original duplicate value has already been removed, so your answer seems to be the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: you can add some case sensitivity in your filter, check this pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgyEew

Comment: Thanks @AbdelkarimELAMEL, this is a great solution. I've added a trim to the check as well, so that it checks for a duplicate excluding leading/trailing spaces, which works nicely.